# How to use Nokogiri to get second image on a list?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to scrape a website, and I'm stuck with this. I want to select each image on the **second li** of a div. I can't get the correct formula. Please, any help?

```
   <div class="carousel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <img alt="Columna de almacenaje " data-bigsrc="/images/cache//c/8/-c87cd5d9a33b662e766480cebec41ffc_w500_h500.jpg" data-hdsrc="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/produits/ES/es/taille_hd/130103_1.jpg" src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//c/8/-c87cd5d9a33b662e766480cebec41ffc_w66_h66.jpg" height="66" width="66">                       
                </li>
                <li>
                   <img alt="Columna de almacenaje " data-bigsrc="/images/cache//2/0/-204c84cf02f6b73d289c2e887b7251ce_w500_h500.jpg" data-hdsrc="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/produits/ES/es/taille_hd/130103_2.jpg" src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//2/0/-204c84cf02f6b73d289c2e887b7251ce_w66_h66.jpg" height="66" width="66">                        
                </li>
                <li>
                   <img alt="Columna de almacenaje " data-bigsrc="/images/cache//a/e/-aeda035baaaad22cb12e1c074d124ece_w500_h500.jpg" data-hdsrc="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/produits/ES/es/taille_hd/130103_3.jpg" src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//a/e/-aeda035baaaad22cb12e1c074d124ece_w66_h66.jpg" height="66" width="66">                        
                </li>
                <li>
                   <img alt="Columna de almacenaje " data-bigsrc="/images/cache//c/f/-cf424c392b338c6d39e525d6396566df_w500_h500.jpg" data-hdsrc="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/produits/ES/es/taille_hd/130103_4.jpg" src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//c/f/-cf424c392b338c6d39e525d6396566df_w66_h66.jpg" height="66" width="66">                        
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my extractor:

```
image = agent.get(doc.parser.at('ul.carousel:nth-child(2) img')['data-hdsrc']).save
```

Comment: `(.carousel ul li:nth-child(2) img')`

Comment: It will still not get it :(

Comment: Comment has been updated.

Comment: Almost there. Still nil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## using xpath

```
agent.get(doc.parser.at("//div[@class='carousel']/ul/li[position()=2]/img")['data-hdsrc']).save
```

## using CSS

```
agent.get(doc.parser.at(".carousel > ul > li:nth-of-type(2) > img")['data-hdsrc']).save
```

Comment: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `evaluate': Invalid predicate: //div[@class='carousel'/ul/li[position()=2]/img (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)

Comment: @Gibson Refresh the page and try.. I updated my answer.

Comment: wont get it, still nil. Wth?

Comment: What is `data-hdsrc` ?

Comment: Its a data attribute for high quality images. I've tried it with simple images and it works, but when trying to crawl the list, it wont get it.

Comment: please see edited question, I've put the real case, maybe you see something. Thanks a lot

Comment: I've tried it, also ['src'], but the problem is the target. It will be nil. Can't explain it.

Comment: Could it be because it's on a slider? Maybe JS?

Comment: Ugh... Thats the problem then. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
response =  Nokogiri::HTML(agent.get('www.site_url.com'))
image = response.css('.carousel ul li:nth-of-type(2) img')[0]
puts image['data-hdsrc'] # Print the attribute value 
image['data-hdsrc'].save # or image['src'], image[data-bigsrc]
```

Comment: Using this, I finally debugged it. I had to validate if image didn't exist, because some of the images where nil.

Comment: @Gibson please select and accept one of the answers as the solution, so this question does not appear as `unanswered` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers provided work. The problem was some of the images in some URLS where nil, so I had to validate each image before proceeding:

```
  if web.at_css('.carousel ul li:nth-child(3) img')
    image3 = agent.get(doc.parser.at(".carousel  ul li:nth-child(3) img")['data-hdsrc']).save("maisonsdumonde/f_deco-#{counter}.jpg")
  else
    puts "No third image"
  end
```